# При попытке записать в Excel: AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only

Tags: python, парсер, excel

Пытаюсь записать в ячейку данные, и выскакивает ошибка AttributeError: 'MergedCell' object attribute 'value' is read-only.

```
Код
sheet[f'C{row}'].value = price.group()
```

Comment: Не знаю как это работает....

Comment: Изменил на             sheet[f'C{row}'].value = price_rub.text